# Formatting number with custom numpunct bring a runtime failure in MSVCP140D.dll

Tags: c++, locale

I'm trying to create a function that create a string with formatted number from an integer. I'm trying to use a locale with custom numpunct that I can customize.
I can't use existing locales because my project is multiplatform and in some platform it might not have locale support so I create one myself from the C one.
Here's the code I added to my project:

```
class comma_numpunct : public std::numpunct<char>
{
  virtual char do_thousands_sep() const
  {
    return '*';
  }

  virtual std::string do_grouping() const
  {
    return "\02";
  }
};

std::string createString(const int x) {
  std::locale comma_locale(std::locale(), new comma_numpunct);
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss.imbue(comma_locale);
  ss << x;
  return ss.str();
}
```

The code compiles fine but when I execute it in debug mode in Visual studio 2015 I get a runtime error, assertion failed in MSVCP140D.dll in `ss << x;`

Here's the full error message:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
---------------------------
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll
File: f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\stdhpp\xmemory0
Line: 106

Expression: "(_Ptr_user & (_BIG_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT - 1)) == 0" && 0

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)

---------------------------
Interrompi   Riprova   Ignora   
---------------------------
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I [can't replicate it using GCC](http://ideone.com/a61m8w), might be a bug in Visual Studio or its library?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I tried in a clean empty project in vs and it works.. It's something about my project that interfere.. But what can interfere with locale?